# Laravel 6 - Policy and Middleware

Tags: php, laravel-6

I have a quick question with regards to both of these function.

**Middleware** - Functionality is to redirect accessibility such as guest, admin or regular user.

**Policy** - What a logged-in / accessed user can do in a page.

I believe that Middleware can be used to hide links, buttons and etc., thus preventing users from proceeding with other functionality within the system making policy somewhat irrelevant.

My question is, if a functionality is guarded / hidden by a policy (@can), will the user still be able to access that functionality by typing the URL address? Policy is simpler but I don't know which is more efficient in handling users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user will still be able to access a URL if they type it in you will need to protect the route using one of the methods you have mentioned (middleware, policies or a check in the controller)

Which one you pick is down to personal choice, I would consider if and how reusable you want it to be across multiple routes/controllers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! I will take note of your advice.

Comment: I agree with this, I tend to use Policies if multiple middlewares (or actions inside the code base) need to be composed with the same checks.  I usually tend to refactor to policies at a later date and initially start with middleware (or just a check at the controller level)